# How to add values in KendoMuliselect TextBox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I have one Grid say employeeGrid and
in Each row of Grid we have edit section (Edit button)
On clicking on Edit button , Popup opens where we have one Mulitiselect text box called empAgent

This is my code for Multiselect

```
var empAgentMultiSelect =   $("#EmpID").kendoMultiSelect({
        placeholder: "Select an agent id",
        dataTextField: "EMPID",
        dataValueField: "EMPNAME",
        autoBind: true,
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            schema: {
                data: "results",
                total: "totalRecords"
            },
            transport: {
                dataType: "json",
                read: {
                    url: "/component/employee.cfc?method=getEmpInfo",
                    data: {
                        btAll       :1,
                        vcAccountID : 1233
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        dataBound:function(){
            var seValues = [];
            var empAgentMultiSelect = $("#EmpID").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            seValues = callAgent();
            empAgentMultiSelect.value(seValues);
    });
```

So when Popup opens on clicking Edit I am adding below code to write data under kendo Mulitselect text box empAgent

```
empAgent :function(){
 var empAgentMultiSelect = $("#EmpID").data("kendoMultiSelect");
 var agentValues = getAgentValues(result.results[0].empAgentID.toString());
 var agentValueArr = [];

 for(var index=0; index< agentValues.length; index++) {
       agentValueArr.push(agentValues[index].empAgentID.toString());
 }

empAgentMultiSelect .value(agentValueArr);
return result.results[0].empAgentID;
}
```

Problem here is 
When I write data inside Multislect text box, It loades getEmpInfo() which gives 2k + data and make my grid hang

Do there is any way by which I can add text inside Multislect text box without calling getEmpInfo() ?

Comment: Try setting the minLength property of the widget to eliminate lots of data returning. Set it to like 3 or 4 and you should be good. Make sure the query inside getEmpInfo() is using startswith. If your using LinQ you could say .Take(125) to only return 125 records

Comment: Yes I can add Min Length parameter in it.
But I don't want to load it first time when I open popup. I just want to add some text values in multiselect text box which I got from some ajax call response, currently when I am assigning those values in it - getEmpInfo() is calling.

Comment: Ok so it's calling getEmpInfo, is the text going in as null and that's why it is returning all your records and getting hung up? If thats the case just say if text == null don't run query